# Is there a neat and clean way to handle nulls with Yields?

Tags: vb.net

```
While CommitReader.Read()
    Yield New Commit() With {
        .FirstValue = CommitReader.GetInt32(CommitReader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")),
        .SecondValue = CommitReader.GetString(CommitReader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")).Trim(),
        'Lots of values
End While
```

I know I can do something like this; however there are 24 properties and I would like to make this part as clean as possible

```
While CommitReader.Read()
    new Commit (){
        Dim index As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")
        If reader.IsDBNull(index) Then
            FirstValue = String.Empty
        Else
            FirstValue = reader(index)
        End If
        index = reader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")
        If reader.IsDBNull(index) Then
            SecondValue = String.Empty
        Else
            SecondValue = reader(index)
        End If
    }
End While
```

Is there a better way to handle this type of thing? I am mainly a C# developer so if the syntax is off a little sorry, I am winging it in VB.

Comment: If you want to convert database NULL values to empty strings, you can do that in the query, e.g. `SELECT COALESCE(FirstValue, '')...`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, while your solution working, want notice that this more question about where you want keep this logic - in database layer or in business logic layer. If you make it in database layer then your business logic assumes then database layer always return empty strings

Comment: @Fabio Yes, I agree that the loss of the information that the column data was NULL could be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shame that SqlDataReader doesn't have the generic Field extension method like DataRow does, but you could define your own extension method (has to be in a module in VB.NET) to help with the null checks, perhaps something like this:

```
<Extension>
Function GetValue(Of T)(rdr As SqlDataReader, i As Integer) As T
    If rdr.IsDBNull(i) Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Return DirectCast(rdr.GetValue(i), T)
End Function
```

And use it something like this:

```
While CommitReader.Read()
    Yield New Commit() With {
        .FirstValue = CommitReader.GetValue(Of Integer?)(CommitReader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")),
        .SecondValue = CommitReader.GetValue(Of String)(CommitReader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")),
        'Lots of values
End While
```

I haven't tested this fully to make sure it handles all data types appropriately (may be worth looking at DataRowExtensions.Field to see how it does it).

Note that you are using String.Empty as the "null" value for strings, while this will use Nothing/null (I also had to remove the .Trim call to avoid NREs).  If you want empty string instead, you could use (adding the Trim back in):

```
.SecondValue = If(CommitReader.GetValue(Of String)(CommitReader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")), String.Empty).Trim()
```

You may also want to move the GetOrdinal calls out of the loop to improve performance.

Comment: Would this e type safe for all primitives, ex. DateTime, Boolean?

Comment: @Robert You will need to use nullable primitive types as the generic parameter if the column is nullable -  as shown for integer in the example, e.g. `GetValue(Of DateTime?)`, otherwise it will return the default value i.e. DateTime.MinValue, or zero for integer types, etc.

Comment: That makes more sense. Thanks

Comment: To improve performance you can get rid from reading value twice  - nice answer :)

Comment: @Robert, for primitive it return default value. `false` for `Boolean`, `DateTime.MinValue` for `DateTime`.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you have repetition in your code  `if ... else ...` condition.
So you can extract it in another method.

For your case generic extension method seems good candidate.

```
Public Module Extensions    
    <Extension>  
    Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(originalValue As object, 
                                            defaultValue As T) As T
        If originalValue = DbNull.Value Then
            Return defaultValue
        End If

        return DirectCast(originalValue, T)
    End Function
End Module
```

Then use it:

```
While CommitReader.Read() = True
    Dim temp = new Commit With
    {
        Dim index As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")
        FirstValue = reader(index).GetValueOrDefault(String.Empty)

        Dim index As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")
        FirstValue = reader(index).GetValueOrDefault(String.Empty)       
    }
End While
```

You can create another overload which return "default" value for given type if it is `DbNull`

```
<Extension>  
Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(originalValue As object) As T
    Return originalValue.GetValueOrDefault(Nothing)
End Function
```

`Nothing` in vb.net is default value, for reference types it is `null` for `Integer` it is `0` for example.

For using this overload you need provide type parameter explicitly

```
While CommitReader.Read() = True
    Dim temp = new Commit With
    {
        Dim index As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")
        FirstValue = reader(index).GetValueOrDefault(Of String)()

        Dim index As Integer = reader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")
        FirstValue = reader(index).GetValueOrDefault(Of String)()       
    }
End While
```

Notice that your solution executing `reader` twice, for checking is it null and for reading value. This can cause "tiny" performance issue.

So in extension method above we read value only once and then check value for `DbNull`.

Answer (score 0):

If you concatenate a string with a Null you get the string:

```
FirstValue = reader(index) & ""
```

Kind of "unprofessional" but saves a lot of coding time if all you are doing is converting a possible Null to an empty string. Easy to forget however, so later data dependent errors may pop up.

Comment: How "unprofessional" solution which _... so later data dependent errors may pop up_ can save coding time?

Comment: The error may occur because, as a coder, you may forgot to add the empty string. If your data very rarely experiences nulls, but a null is possible in the DB, an error can occur. Best to defend against a known possible case.