# Why is this returning Index out of bound exception

Tags: vb.net

When I get to the Read loop I get an index out of bounds error. I think its on the reader ordinal value, but I am not sure why I am getting it.

```
Private Function Create(Reader As SqlDataReader) As IEnumerable(Of MyObject)

        SetOrdinals(MyObjectReader)
        Dim MyObjects = New List(Of MyObject)

        While MyObjectReader.Read()
            Dim Temp = New MyObject() With {
                .FirstValue = MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of Integer)(MyObjectReader(FirstValue_Ord)),
                .SecondValue = If(MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of String)(MyObjectReader(SecondValue_Ord)), String.Empty).Trim(),
                .ThirdValue = If(MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of String)(MyObjectReader(ThirdValue_Ord)), String.Empty).Trim(),                
            MyObjects.Add(Temp)
        End While
        Return MyObjects

    End Function

    Private Sub SetOrdinals(MyObjectReader As SqlDataReader)
        FirstValueOrd = MyObjectReader.GetOrdinal("FirstValue")
        SecondValue_Ord = MyObjectReader.GetOrdinal("SecondValue")
        ThirdValue_Ord = MyObjectReader.GetOrdinal("ThirdValue")        
    End Sub

End Class


Public Module Extensions

    <Extension>
    Function GetValue(Of T)(rdr As SqlDataReader, i As Integer) As T
        If rdr.IsDBNull(i) Then
            Return Nothing
        End If
        Return DirectCast(rdr.GetValue(i), T)
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: It seems like you're reinventing the wheel!  `SqlDataReader` already has methods called `GetString`, `GetInteger`, etc. which do what your `GetValue` method does.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Sorry for coming back to this late.  The `GetString` etc. methods require null checks, which is why I suggested the `GetValue` extension in the [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40683355) - similar to extension method for `DataRow`.  Is there a better way to handle that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be passing in the ordinal to the `GetValue` calls:

```
While MyObjectReader.Read()
    Dim Temp = New MyObject() With {
        .FirstValue = MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of Integer)(FirstValue_Ord),
        .SecondValue = If(MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of String)(SecondValue_Ord), String.Empty).Trim(),
        .ThirdValue = If(MyObjectReader.GetValue(Of String)(ThirdValue_Ord), String.Empty).Trim()
    }
    MyObjects.Add(Temp)
End While
```

Comment: Sorry that was me not fully copying the code over. The actual code uses the Ordinal

Comment: @Robert The difference is that the parameter should be just the ordinal - `FirstValue_Ord` instead of `MyObjectReader(FirstValue_Ord)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here my version :)

```
Private Function Create(reader As SqlDataReader) As IEnumerable(Of MyObject)
    Dim objects As New List(Of MyObject)()        

    Dim ordinals As New Ordinals(reader)
    While reader.Read()
        Dim Temp As New MyObject With 
        {
            .FirstValue = reader.GetValueOrDefault(Of Integer)(ordinals.FirstValue),
            .SecondValue = reader.GetValueOrDefault(ordinals.SecondValue, "").Trim(),
            .ThirdValue = reader.GetValueOrDefault(ordinals.ThirdValue, "").Trim()
        }

        objects.Add(Temp)
    End While
    Return MyObjects

End Function

Private Class Ordinals
    Public Property FirstValue As Integer
    Public Property SecondValue As Integer
    Public Property ThirdValue As Integer

    Public Sub New(reader As SqlDataReader)
        FirstValue = reader.GetOrdinal(nameOf(FirstValue))
        SecondValue = reader.GetOrdinal(nameOf(SecondValue))
        ThirdValue = reader.GetOrdinal(nameOf(ThirdValue))
    End Sub
End Class


Public Module Extensions
    <Extension>
    Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(reader As SqlDataReader, ordinal As Integer) As T
        Return reader.GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ordinal, Nothing)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(reader As SqlDataReader, 
                                     ordinal As Integer, 
                                     defaultValue As T) As T
        Dim value = reader(ordinal)
        If value = DbNull.Value Then
            Return defaultValue
        End If
        Return DirectCast(value, T)
    End Function
End Module
```

Because extension method execute checking for `DbNull.Value` against already extracted object, we get rid from reading same value twice from `SqlDataReader`.
`SqlDataReader.IsDbNull(index)` reads value before checking for `DbNull`.

Extension method have two overloads:
 - One which return default value of given type, if value is `DbNull.Value`. `Nothing` in vb.net is default value of type.
 - And one which takes parameter for default value you want return if value is `DbNull.Value`. Possibility pass default value makes lines where you create new object shorter and more readable.  We get rid of inline `if` statement.

Your extension method with name `GetValue` have "side effects". By name consumer of this method expect to get value from `SqlDataReader`. So he can expect to get `DbNull.Value` if database query return `NULL`, but instead he get `null` for string or `0` for integer. Name `GetValueOrDefault` is little bid more informative, so you don't need to go inside method to check what is doing.